# How do I use WindowsVirtualDesktopPowershell Cmdlets to start an application in "Show this window on all desktops" mode?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to learn how to programmatically control the Windows 10 Virtual Deskop. I've found [this WindowsVirtualDesktopPowershell library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows-virtual-desktop/overview) but it's taking some time to find [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/?source=recommendations)/examples of my usecase:

I'm trying to figure out how to *start* an app in "Show this window on all desktops" mode: as though I opened it, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, right-clicked it, and selected "Show this window on all desktops."

Can this library do that? If so, can someone provide an example of how to create a powershell script that, when double clicked, opens a program on all desktops?

I'm using Windows 10 with a local virtual desktop.